# How to run a function every 24 hour in GoogleSheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written some codes in Google Sheet to send email to a list of people in a Google sheet. But want to run that function every 24 hour automatically, so that it keep sending emails every 24 hours, until there is email id in the defined range. Currently I have run in and execute manually to send emails.

We have some list of people who need to acknowledge details and email ids of people who does not acknowledge get saved in google sheet. Every time we need to send manual email. So this is to automate the daily task.

```js
function sendNotification(){
  var sheet = getSheetByName("testRollcallremaining");
  var rows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var cols = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,rows-1,cols);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (i in data){
    var name = data[i][0];
    var to = data[i][1];
    sendEmail(to, "Subject","Message Body Here");
  }
}
```

This code should execute/run every 24 hours until. Without doing anything manually.

Comment: Did you tried with using `setInterval()` or you are looking for something else .

Comment: This is not going to work reliably on the client side. You'd have to leave the page open 24 hours a day for it to do what you need. A much better solution would be to have a server side job running under a scheduler to read the sheet data and build/send an email

Comment: Then he should use `cronJob`

Comment: Since this is Google Apps Script - all you need to do is set up a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) for this to run once a day.

Comment: Thanks ross, the trigger worked perfectly fine.